# Django can't find the URL pattern

Tags: python, html, django

I'm new to Django and I'm making wiki website based on markdown. I am having one problem. Django can't match the path in html to urls.py. It happens when I try to open wiki entries. It gives me the following error. I have already passed the parameter to 'page', I honestly have no idea what to do.

```
Using the URLconf defined in wiki.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
wiki/<str:page> [name='page']
search [name='search']
create [name='create']
addentry [name='add_entry']
nomatches [name='nomatches']
results [name='results']
edit/<str:page> [name='edit']
random [name='random']
The current path, { url 'page' entry }, didn't match any of these.
```

Please, tell me how can I fix this.

index. html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>All Pages</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <a href="{ url 'page' entry }"><li>{{ entry }}</li></a>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:page>", views.viewpage, name="page"), 
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("create", views.create, name="create"),
    path("addentry", views.add_entry, name="add_entry"),
    path("nomatches", views.search, name="nomatches"),
    path("results", views.search, name="results"),
    path("edit/<str:page>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("random", views.random, name="random")
]
```

part of views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })


def viewpage(request, page):
    content = util.get_entry(page)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/page.html", {
        "content": markdown2.markdown(content),
        "title":page
    })
```

page.html

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
{{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<a href="/edit/{{ title }}">edit</a>
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    {{ content|safe }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/#tags
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: It should be `{% url 'page' entry %}`, not `{ url 'page' entry }`.

Comment: Oh god, the syntax... Thanks so much. But I feel sorta embarrassed now lol.

Answer (score 0):

Since the URL for 'page' is 'wiki/<str: page>' you need to define a get_absolute_url method on your class model that contains the object in question, so do add this method in the models.py class that contains page:

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('page',kwargs={str:self.str})
```

Then, in the template, you can refer to it as
`{% object.get_absolute_url%}`.